# Soldering USB sockets and GSM module with hot air

Tags: soldering, stencil, hot-air

I'm not very experienced with soldering, so I need advice.

I'm going to solder this socket - https://www.te.com/usa-en/product-2305018-2.html

[image: photo of the socket]

How should I do this properly? I'm going use a PCB stencil, solder-paste and hot air. But this connector is covered with plastic and silicone.

And another question - how do I solder this GSM modem module? It's built on a piece of PCB with a few pads on the bottom. Like this one:

[image: image of GSM modem PCB]

Comment: Use a toaster oven. Put some paste on an unused pad so you can see when it melts. The large connector will take some time to come up to temperature after the paste on the unused pad melts.

Answer (score 2):

As the others have commented, you really would want to use an oven. A hot air tool cannot give the volume of heat required to bring everything up to the right temperature. Note that your mobile module is itself a pcb with components on it and needs special care in regards to the temperature and the temperature profile. They also have substantial thermal mass.

You might be able to solder the connector with a hot air tool, but I’d expect you’ll melt one or two practicing.

Unless you have access to an oven I’d suggest using the various boards that have the module and required parts already soldered for you. Believe me, even with an oven it is a challenge. If something doesn’t work you’re left pondering if it is a fault with the module, the soldering, the pcb, the layout, the components , software and so on. I have a graveyard of dead modules as evidence.

Answer (score 1):

Page 5 of the [USB Socket](https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=showdoc&DocId=Specification+Or+Standard%7F108-115129-2%7FA%7Fpdf%7FEnglish%7FENG_SS_108-115129-2_A.pdf%7F2305018-2), Fig 2 Recommended reflow temp profile: 150'C - 90sec - ramp to 250'C.

Page 73 of [BG96 soldering instruction](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiv0_GQl7nyAhV3TDABHdSwAjMQFnoECAUQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fforums.quectel.com%2Fuploads%2Fshort-url%2FijpLg6mZNzp1mMtEbdPSbDRxggM.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0DuyxfABcWJH3pwxfUmdyL) says *It is suggested that the peak reflow temperature is 235~245ºC (for SnAg3.0Cu0.5 alloy). The absolute
max reflow temperature is 260ºC.*

I do: 1) place a thermocouple (a digital thermometer) near, 2) apply solder paste using a syringe, 3) place a device (this is the hardest part), 4) blow hot air.

Practice on a bare board first. Solder paste finds right place while curing (heating). So,I did not need stencil. Stencil did not work well for me.